# Edittext is leaking using leakcanary

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, memory-leaks, leakcanary

**Logs of leak canary**
leakTrace=
┬
├─ java.lang.Thread
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Thread name: 'Studio:InputCon'
│    GC Root: Java local variable
│    ↓ thread Thread.
│                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ InputConnectionWrapper.mTarget
│                             ~~~~~~~
├─ com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ EditableInputConnection.mTargetView
│                              ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    mContext instance of
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ AppCompatEditText.mContext
╰

Answer (score 0):

If you would have provided the code snippet that would be much better.

1. Edit text shouldn't be static. Like (static Edittext edtText;)
2. Make edit text reference null in onDestroy () of an activity.